# Regarding property setMinScale(scale) and setMaxScale(scale) in ArcGIS API for JavaScript?

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

I am new to programming in JSAPI.

I have two dynamic layers and I want to set the property setMinScale(scale) and setMaxScale(scale) to layers so how do I Set ?

ex. I tried using layer.setMinScale(0) but it is not working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it have to be maxScale or minScale for your layer defination as following example. more info is on arcgis javascript doc. [site](http://help.arcgis.com/en/webapi/javascript/arcgis/help/jsapi_start.htm#jsapi/dynamiclayerinfo.htm)....

> maxScale
>
> The maximum visible scale for each layer in the map service. If the
>   map is zoomed in beyond this scale the layer will not be visible. A
>   value of 0 means that the layer does not have a maximum scale. This
>   property is only available for map services published using ArcGIS
>   Server 10 SP1 or later. Code snippets:
>
> dynamicLayerInfo.maxScale = 1000000;
>
> dynamicLayerInfo.minScale = 0;

.

> minScale
>
> The minimum visible scale for each layer in the map service.
>   If the map is zoomed out beyond this scale the layer will not be
>   visible. A value of 0 means that the layer does not have a minimum
>   scale. This property is only available for map services published
>   using ArcGIS Server 10 SP1 or later. Code snippets:
>
> dynamicLayerInfo.maxScale = 1000000;
>
> dynamicLayerInfo.minScale = 0;

i hope it helps you...

Comment: Hi Aragon,                                                thanks for your reply. I tried according to  API doc.  layer1.maxScale = 1000000;                        layer1.minScale = 0;   also check the REST link for scale its showing minimum scale 1.47914381   & max. scale is 4513.988     Let me add code here

Comment: var dynamicMapServiceLayer1 = new esri.layers.ArcGISDynamicMapServiceLayer("http://myserver:6080/arcgis/rest/services/layer11/MapServer",{"opacity":0.25});                                        
      
         dynamicMapServiceLayer1.setVisibleLayers([0,1]);
          dynamicMapServiceLayer1.maxScale = 50000;
          dynamicMapServiceLayer1.minScale = 0;
                      
        map.addLayer(dynamicMapServiceLayer1);                        // Is my code is wrong ??.. please let me know.. thanks

Comment: Hello All,                                                  Its resolved . I have customized my code as per instructions given by @Argon thanks Argon..Please check following link also  http://forums.arcgis.com/threads/61576-Dynamic-layer-info-minScale-maxScale-bug-in-ArcGIS-JavaScript-API-3.0